# !important border-color of adjacent <td>'s

Tags: php, html, css

I have a php code that generates hundreds of `<tr>` and `<td>` tags.
My issue is as follows,
I have the following:

`<td style="border-color-right: black">X</td>
<td style="border-color-right: grey">X</td>`

I would like for the 2nd `<td>`'s border-color to carry more importance so that the shared border appears grey instead of black. Is there an importance or inheritance tag I can use in the 2nd td?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question right, then you should make it so:
https://jsfiddle.net/maxim_mazurok/pzjamue4/1/

```
.black {
    border-right-color: grey
}
.grey {
    border-color: grey
}
```

Shared border is grey, exactly as you wanted.

Also you can try this: https://jsfiddle.net/maxim_mazurok/vw8oz7mk/

```
.border\-color\-right\: {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
}
.black {
    border-color: black;
    border-right-style: none;
}
.grey {
    border-color: grey
}
```